# Export sql data to text file

Tags: vb.net

how can i align the address1 nicely after export to text file for vb.net

[image]

```html
 Dim sDtFile As String = ""

        sDtFile = Format(Today, "yyyy") & Format(Today, "MM") & Format(Today, "dd")
        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\yymok\Desktop\RJL\test_" & sDtFile & ".txt")

        If gvResult.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            writer.WriteLine("")
            writer.WriteLine("{0,15} {1,14} {2,16} {3,14} {4,25}", "Customer Name", "Customer No", "Chinese Name", "IC No", "Address1")
            writer.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

            For i As Integer = 0 To gvResult.Rows.Count - 1

                For j As Integer = 0 To gvResult.Columns.Count - 1

                    writer.Write(vbTab & gvResult.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() & vbTab & "|")

                Next
                writer.WriteLine("")
                writer.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

            Next
        End If
        writer.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Exported")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string formatting functionality that you use for the headers. Declare an array of format strings outside your loop:

```
Dim formatStrings = {"{0,15}", "{1,14}", "{2,16}", "{3,14}", "{4,25}"
```

Then, inside your loop you can use the appropriate format string based on the column:

```
writer.Write(formatStrings(j) & " | ", gvResult.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value)
```